# IOS in app purchase currency format for Chinese Yuan

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, in-app-purchase

I'm running into a problem when trying to set up the In-App-Purchase price string in the Chinese store.  If an in game product is 30.00rmb I want it to show ¥30.00, but right now it is showing CN¥30.00.  Below is the code I use:

```
SKProduct* product

NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = product.priceLocale;
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.formatterBehavior = NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4;

return [formatter stringFromNumber:product.price]
```

where product is a SKProduct that is passed in as a parameter.

Keep in mind this works for all other Apple stores in other currencies, but it's just not working for the Chinese Apple store.

I would really like the end result to be ¥30.00.

Thanks!

PS. Another bug I'm seeing that could be related is that I am getting rare edge cases of the price string showing up as 30,00; That is with a comma and no currency symbol.  Maybe this is somehow related?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code ::

```
NSString *price = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [product.priceLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol], product.price];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response man, but although this would work for the Chinese currency it wouldn't work for other countries that have their currency symbol in the end (ex. 100.00£).  However, I have figured out what is causing the problem.  The locale depends on the user's account region and language settings.  So my testing account had region set to China, but language set to English, that's why it was using the weird locale format.